# What does it mean when I test SSH connection to GitHub it says terminating, 1 bad configuration options?

Tags: github, ssh, terminal

Using Gitbash, I made an SSH and I tried to test it writing in terminal:
$ ssh -T git@github.com

What returns is:
.ssh/config line 3: keyword identityfile extra arguments at end of line
.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options

What does that mean?

Comment: It tells you to have a look into `~/.ssh/config` - why don't you show us the contents of that file so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Figured it out thank you. I did have to go into vim~/.ssh/config and saw line 3 IdentityFile was missing a character.